# issues with backing out of a UIViewController while JSON is still being parsed

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I have a UIViewController where I do some JSON parsing....Now, if I back out of the UIViewController (pop it from the stack) while the JSON its still being parsed, I get the following error:

```
-[SearchResultsViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb23dd50
```

Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

NB: I am guessing this is because the parser is calling some method in my UIViewController class...

Answer (score 1):

This would mean that your JSON finished parsing and then sent the results to the search results controller which was deallocated because you popped your view. You should cancel your JSON parser or force it to not publish the data to the search results controller when you pop your view controller.

Comment: how do I do that ?? any hints ?

Comment: You could simply check if it's nil before sending it any messages. if(searchResultsViewController != nil){ //do whatever you are doing right now}

Comment: is there a way to cancel from the searchResultsViewController ?

Comment: If you keep a reference to the JSON parser that you started then you could tell it to stop/cancel or set it's delegate/callback to nil.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do something like this:

JSONParser.delegate = nil;

or stop parser before pop view controller

Comment: how do I do that? any hints ?

Comment: how do I stop parser before popping the view controller ?